# Can i move commits from dev to master using rebase?

Tags: git, commit, rebase

I discovered recently how to use the rebase command.

I have a master and a dev branch and to me it seems really convenient to just `git rebase dev master` when I want to move the functional dev to the master branch.
(avoiding to do a pull request from dev to master and then using the `git rebase master dev` command (because the pull request brings the master 1 commit ahead of dev)).

Is it a correct way of doing it? what am I missing? What are the possible drawbacks?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

In general, the golden rule is not to rebase branches that other people are using.... dev and master sound like candidates... unless you are the only developer and you know what you are doing.

Rebasing feature branches developed by a single developer? Yeah, sure... why not? No one will use it until it is merged to whatever common branch.... and if people actually start using it before it is merged (it happens from time to time), it should be understood that their base branch might move anytime.

Comment: and what about merging the dev branch to master (on master: git merge dev)? is that an option that is commonly used? (to avoid the 1 commit on master caused by the pull request?)